# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'java': 'java'

Tags: streamlit

I am facing this error after I have deployed my streamlit app on streamlit sharing. The app is running well on my localhost but not after deploying. I think it is not running the bash commands on the server which I have in my streamlit app.

```
    # Performs the descriptor calculation
    bashCommand = "java -Xms2G -Xmx2G -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar ./PaDEL-Descriptor/PaDEL-Descriptor.jar -removesalt -standardizenitro -fingerprints -descriptortypes ./PaDEL-Descriptor/PubchemFingerprinter.xml -dir ./ -file descriptors_output.csv"
    process = subprocess.Popen(bashCommand.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    output, error = process.communicate()
    os.remove('molecule.smi')
```

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGgvO.jpg)

I am getting this as an error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'java': 'java'
Traceback:
File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/streamlit/script_runner.py", line 332, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "/app/bioactivity-prediction/app.py", line 69, in <module>
    desc_calc()
File "/app/bioactivity-prediction/app.py", line 13, in desc_calc
    process = subprocess.Popen(bashCommand.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 800, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1551, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
```

Also here is a link to my deployed app:
https://share.streamlit.io/rahul97532/bioactivity-prediction/app.py

Answer (score 0):

To install java on Streamlit Cloud, you need to create a file `packages.txt` with the line `default-jre` in it, as demonstrated in this repository example:

https://github.com/randyzwitch/test-java/blob/main/packages.txt

Comment: If this solved your problem, please mark the question as answered so the next person who comes across this knows the solution.